# How to fix a game of roulette (functions, loops, and conditional statements)

Tags: r, function, loops, conditional-statements

I am trying to play roulette, but it doesn't really work as intended.

```
red_fields <- c(32, 19, 21, 25, 34, 27, 36, 30, 23, 5, 16, 1, 14, 9, 18, 7, 12, 3)
black_fields <- setdiff(1:36, red_fields)
zero <- 0
color <- c("red", "black", "green")

play_roulette <- function(bet, number, bet_color) {
  draw <- sample(0:36, 1)
  tibble(
    winning_number = draw,
   winning_color = if (draw == red_fields) {
      "red"
    } else 
      if (draw == black_fields) {
      "black"
    } else {
      "green"
    },
   bet_color = color,
    your_number = number,
    your_bet = bet,
    your_return = if (number == draw | bet_color == winning_color) {
      bet * 36
    } else {
      0
    }
  )
}

play_roulette(bet = 1, number = 32, bet_color = "red" )
```

Is there an "easy" way to fix this code? Without bet_color and color it worked pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

```
play_roulette <- function(bet, number, bet_color) {
  draw <- sample(0:36, 1)
  tibble(
    winning_number = draw,
    winning_color = if (draw %in% red_fields) { ##changed to %in%
      "red"
    } else 
      if (draw %in% black_fields) { ##changed to %in%
        "black"
      } else {
        "green"
      },
    bet_color = bet_color, ##originally color which resulted in c("red", "black", "green") as answer
    your_number = number,
    your_bet = bet,
    your_return = if (number == draw | bet_color == winning_color) {
      bet * 36
    } else {
      0
    }
  )
}

play_roulette(bet = 1, number = 32, bet_color = "red" )
```

Basically instead of `draw == red_fields` we actually want `draw %in% red_fields`. Similarly we alwso want `draw %in% black_fileds`. Here's the difference in what these return:

```
36 == red_fields
##  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
36 %in% red_fields
## [1] TRUE
```

Finally, there is an issue with the tibble being `bet_color = color` - I think it's more likely that you want `bet_color = bet_color`.

Answer (score 0):

Changes to make:

```
draw == red_fields     ### to ###    draw %in% red_fields
draw == black_fields   ### to ###    draw %in% black_fields
bet_color = color      ### to ###    color = bet_color
```

The change from `==` to `%in%` will ensure that you have a *single* logical value going into your `if()` statements. Otherwise, with the `==`, you'll get a vector comparing `draw` to every value in `red_fields` and `black_fields`, which doesn't work well in `if()`. You could wrap this in an `any()` function, but it's quicker to just use `%in%`.

The `bet_color = color` replacement looks like a genuine error. Currently your code will return a 3 row tibble with a value in `bet_color` for each value in `color` (as defined at the start as `color <- c("red", "black", "green")`). I presume you want a single row with the correct returns.

After fixing that, you might want to check what's happening here: `bet_color == winning_color`. Is `bet_color` the argument being passed to the function, or the one being created in the `tibble()` call? If you swapped `bet_color` and `color`, then it'll definitly be the one being passed to the function. Otherwise, you have two variables with the same name, one *inside* your `tibble()` and one *outside* of it. You can be explicit in which one you're refering to by using `.env$bet_color` to refer to the one *outside* of the `tibble()` (i.e. your function argument) and `.data$bet_color` to refer to the one *inside* your `tibble()`